# Why does this floating-point loop terminate at 1,000,000?

Tags: c, floating-point

The answer to this sample homework problem is "1,000,000", but I do not understand why:

> What is the output of the following code?
>
> ```
> int main(void) {
>   float k = 1;
>   while (k != k + 1) {
>     k = k + 1;
>   }
>   printf(“%g”, k); // %g means output a floating point variable in decimal
> }
> ```
>
> If the program runs indefinitely but produces no output, write INFINITE LOOP as the answer to the question. All of the programs compile and run. They may or may not contain serious errors, however. You should assume that int is four bytes. You should assume that float has the equivalent of six decimal digits of precision.  You may round your answer off to the nearest power of 10 (e.g., you can say 1,000 instead of 2<sup>10</sup> (i.e., 1024)).

I do not understand why the loop would ever terminate.

Comment: is this a copy-paste of a homework or test question?

Comment: That is homework... but anyway, "INFINITE LOOP".

Comment: I tend to ask the OP if it's homework and let them make the decision. It's up to them if they want to cheat, after all, and they would be foolish to think their educators do not watch sites like this. In any case, there's ample precedent of people using homework-like questions for self education. Case in point is all the questions in books like K&R or teach-yourself-whatever.

Comment: this is a sample question, and the answer has been provided. but i couldn't figure out how to reach that answer, so i asked the community for help. im not cheating on my homework

Comment: You could just execute the code to see the result. I got an infinite loop.

Comment: I doubt that, @marion, you just didn't wait long enough. This is a good idea why executing the code is not always the right thing to do. For a start, you probably don't *have* a float with 6 digits precision. Secondly, you're not _thinking_. Even the dumbest of scientists will hypothesise before blindly coming up with experiments :-) No offence intended. This question is supposed to make you _think_ about the answer and how computers work.

Comment: @pax: I think mariomaiden might be right actually that the loop was infinite on that implementation. If the comparison is being done with excess precision, but the assignment rounds back to 32 bit, then you have an infinite loop. Which just shows you're right too, that if you're supposed to assume float has 6 decimal digits of precision, then Intel is not a good place to test code, since the CPU has an 80 bit floating point type and the compiler's not afraid to use it...

Comment: With gcc I had to change to `while(1) { float j = k + 1; if (j == k) break;` to get this to terminate. With optimisation I needed -ffloat-store too, although with -O2 or -O3 I think it'd terminate eventually somewhere around 2^65 even without -ffloat-store. It ran in 0.2s on my machine, so unless marionmaiden's computer is preposterously old, I doubt that it's lack of patience :-)

Comment: @pax: As Steve said, I got a big value but the program didn't stopped at all; @Steve: with your answer, I think me and @pax are satisfied

Comment: Marionmaiden didn't wait long enough. If her implementation stores 32 bit floats but keeps 80 bit long doubles in registers to do comparisons, the answer will be around pow(2,24) but she'll have to wait for around pow(2,65) iterations. ---edit--- OK, I see, if -ffloat-store is used then the loop is infinite.

Comment: What I found with -O1 on the original code was that the value was truncated by the assignment `k = k + 1`, but not in the comparison `k == k + 1`. So it was as if -ffloat-store were in use, whether or not it actually was. It wasn't until -O2 that `k` was optimised entirely into a register, and the value was climbing indefinitely (although obviously I couldn't wait for it to hit 2^65). That's just some random version of GCC, though, no guarantees whether it's consistent with other versions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't run forever for the simple reason that floating point numbers are not perfect.

At some point, `k` will become big enough so that adding 1 to it will have no effect.

At that point, `k` will be equal to `k+1` and your loop will exit.

Floating point numbers can be differentiated by a single unit only when they're in a certain range.

As an example, let's say you have an integer type with 3 decimal digits of precision for a positive *integer* and a single-decimal-digit exponent.

With this, you can represent the numbers 0 through 999 perfectly as 000x10<sup>0</sup> through 999x10<sup>0</sup> (since 10<sup>0</sup> is 1):

What happens when you want to represent 1000? You need to use 100x10<sup>1</sup>. This is still represented perfectly.

However, there is *no* accurate way to represent 1001 with this scheme, the next number you can represent is 101x10<sup>1</sup> which is 1010.

So, when you add 1 to 1000, you'll get the closest match which is 1000.

Answer (score 5):

The code is using a `float` variable.

As specified in the question, `float` has 6 digits of precision, meaning that any digits after the sixth will be inaccurate.  Therefore, once you pass a million, the final digit will be inaccurate, so that incrementing it can have no effect.

Comment: I suggest you run the OP's code and see that you are completely wrong. On typical implementations, the result will be about 16 million (or it might not stop at all).

Answer (score 4):

The output of this program is **not specified** by the C standard, since the semantics of the `float` type are not specified.  One likely result (what you will get on a platform for which `float` arithmetic is evaluated in IEEE-754 single precision) is `2^24`.

All integers smaller than `2^24` are exactly representable in single precision, so the computation will not stop before that point.  The next representable single precision number after `2^24`, however, is `2^24 + 2`.  Since `2^24 + 1` is exactly halfway between that number and `2^24`, in the default IEEE-754 rounding mode it rounds to the one whose trailing bit is zero, which is `2^24`.

Other likely answers include `2^53` and `2^64`.  Still other answers are possible.  `Infinity` (the floating-point value) could result on a platform for which the default rounding mode is round up, for example.  As others have noted, an infinite loop is also possible on platforms that evaluate floating-point expressions in a wider type (which is the source of all sorts of programmer confusion, but allowed by the C standard).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, on most C compilers, this will run forever (infinite loop), though the precise behavior is implementation defined.

The reason that most compilers will give an infinite loop is that they evaluate all floating point expressions at *double* precision and only round values back to *float* (single) precision when storing into a variable.  So when the value of k gets to about 2^24, `k == k + 1` will still evaluate as false (as a double can hold the value k+1 without rounding), but the `k = k + 1` assignment will be a noop, as k+1 needs to be rounded to fit into a float

**edit**

gcc on x86 gets this infinite loop behavior.  Interestingly on x64 it does not, as it uses sse instructions which do the comparison in float precision.

Comment: Which C compilers did you try this on?  I tried on GCC and it halted almost instantly.

Comment: even if you use double it will stop at about 1e16-1e17. Because floating point is always finite. Floats have 6-7 digits of precision so it stops at 1e6. The same for doubles which have 16-17 digits of precision. If there's any difference, that's because you're using different compiler options for floating point math

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: No, it won't stop. The comparison is done in double precision, but the addition uses float. So once the float reaches 2^24, it doesn't increase anymore, but the comparison never fails. If you used double for the variable, it would stop after a very long time (unless you have an extremely optimising compiler which would just set the result to 2^53).

Comment: @gnasher729 I didn't think of the promotion rule at the time of this comment